# Laravel react auth scaffolding

Tags: laravel

According to the Laravel 7 docs 
// Generate login / registration scaffolding...

```
php artisan ui react --auth
```

From my understanding this would generate the auth with the react component being used as the auth view.

However after I run it in my project the auth is created with blade files and react is setup as the example component it usually creates.
So is this command:
"Install ui react AND auth as it normally does"?
Or is there away I can get it to fire up the auth with React being the "view" used?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the wording of your question. Are you asking if there is way to do the registration scaffolding **without** using React?

Comment: What it does, and what is intended behaviour I suppose, is create the blade files and the example components. From there you can create your custom components and drop them in the blade templates. However (for me) it also created the blade files using JS for logout handling etc.

Comment: Would you like to use React for the entire view layer of your application? If so, you can use the php artisan preset react command instead of php artisan ui react --auth. This command will replace the default Blade templates with React components for all views in your application, not just the authentication views.